# How to add an countable variable into an function and eventnames in kinetic.js?

Tags: javascript, variables, for-loop, mouseevent, kineticjs

How can I add an countable variable into an function and eventnames in kinetic.js?
i have 2 circles and want to have more, the circles have mouseover events and functions and so on. I don't want to copy paste the circle functions, i want to have it in a "for" loop. But i don't know how to add the variables in the function-names and the event-names.
Thank you for Answering!

Here is my Code:

```
<head>
        <script src="kinetic-v4.0.0.js">    </script>
        <script>

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var sfcolor = '#00ff00'         
            var nfcolor = '#0000ff'         
            var cfcolor = '#ff0000'         
            var smcolor = '#009a00'         
            var nmcolor = '#00009a'         
            var cmcolor = '#9a0000'         
            var slcolor = '#007000'         
            var nlcolor = '#000070'         
            var clcolor = '#700000'
            var sradius = 50
            var strokeWidth = 1
            function drawCircle1/*here an countable variable*/(sx, sy, sradius, sstrokeWidth, containerID) {
                var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: containerID, width: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1), height: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1) });
                var circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
                //circle
                var scircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    radius: sradius,
                    fill:  {
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    },
                    stroke: slcolor,
                    strokeWidth: sstrokeWidth
                });

                mouseover_event1/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2/*here an countable var*/");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                };
                scircle.on("mouseover.event1/*here an countable var*/", mouseover_event1/*here an countable var*/);

                mouseout_event1/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(slcolor);
                    scircle.off("click.event2/*here an countable var*/");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                }
                scircle.on("mouseout.event1/*here an countable var*/", mouseout_event1/*here an countable var*/);

                click_event1 = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, cfcolor, 0.5, cmcolor, 1, clcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(clcolor);
                    scircle.off("mouseout.event1/*here an countable var*/");
                    scircle.off("mouseover.event1/*here an countable var*/");
                    scircle.off("click.event1/*here an countable var*/");
                    scircle.on("click.event2/*here an countable var*/", click_event2/*here an countable var*/);

                    circleLayer.draw();
                };

                click_event2/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    scircle.on("mouseout.event1/*here an countable var*/", mouseout_event1/*here an countable var*/);
                    scircle.on("mouseover.event1/*here an countable var*/", mouseover_event1/*here an countable var*/);
                    scircle.on("click.event1/*here an countable var*/", click_event1/*here an countable var*/);
                    scircle.off("click.event2/*here an countable var*/");
                    circleLayer.draw();
                };

                scircle.on("click.event1"/*here an countable var*/, click_event1/*here an countable var*/);


                circleLayer.add(scircle);
                stage.add(circleLayer);
        }
function drawCircle2/*here an countable var*/(sx, sy, sradius, sstrokeWidth, containerID)/*it is the same function with the variables count up manual*/ {
            var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: containerID, width: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1), height: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1) });
            var circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            //circle
            var scircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                x: sx,
                y: sy,
                radius: sradius,
                fill:  {
                start: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    radius: 0
                },
                end: {
                    x: 0,
                    y: 0,
                    radius: sradius
                },
                colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                },
                stroke: slcolor,
                strokeWidth: sstrokeWidth
            });

            mouseover_event3/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                this.setFill({
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                });
                this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                scircle.off("click.event4/*here an countable var*/");
                circleLayer.draw();
            };
            scircle.on("mouseover.event3/*here an countable var*/", mouseover_event3/*here an countable var*/);

            mouseout_event3/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                this.setFill({
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                });
                this.setStroke(slcolor);
                scircle.off("click.event4/*here an countable var*/");
                circleLayer.draw();
            }
            scircle.on("mouseout.event3/*here an countable var*/", mouseout_event3/*here an countable var*/);

            click_event3/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                this.setFill({
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, cfcolor, 0.5, cmcolor, 1, clcolor]
                });
                this.setStroke(clcolor);
                scircle.off("mouseout.event3/*here an countable var*/");
                scircle.off("mouseover.event3/*here an countable var*/");
                scircle.off("click.event3/*here an countable var*/");
                scircle.on("click.event4/*here an countable var*/", click_event4/*here an countable var*/);

                circleLayer.draw();
            };

            click_event4/*here an countable var*/ = function() {
                this.setFill({
                    start: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: 0
                    },
                    end: {
                        x: 0,
                        y: 0,
                        radius: sradius
                    },
                    colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                });
                this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                scircle.on("mouseout.event3/*here an countable var*/", mouseout_event3/*here an countable var*/);
                scircle.on("mouseover.event3/*here an countable var*/", mouseover_event3/*here an countable var*/);
                scircle.on("click.event3/*here an countable var*/", click_event3/*here an countable var*/);
                scircle.off("click.event4/*here an countable var*/");
                circleLayer.draw();
            };

            scircle.on("click.event3/*here an countable var*/", click_event3/*here an countable var*/);


            circleLayer.add(scircle);
            stage.add(circleLayer);
        }
        window.onload = function() {
            drawCircle1/*here an countable var*/(sradius, sradius, sradius, strokeWidth, "1"/*here an countable var*/);
            drawCircle2/*here an countable var*/(sradius, sradius, sradius, strokeWidth, "2"/*here an countable var*/);
        };

    </script>


</head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="1"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="2"></div> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sorry to ask, but do you really need count the event id up? 
Seems that you want to have several circles, each one with their own isolated events, is that?

See if the following code is what you looking for

```
<head>
        <script src="kinetic-v4.0.0.js">    </script>
        <script>

            var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
            var sfcolor = '#00ff00'         
            var nfcolor = '#0000ff'         
            var cfcolor = '#ff0000'         
            var smcolor = '#009a00'         
            var nmcolor = '#00009a'         
            var cmcolor = '#9a0000'         
            var slcolor = '#007000'         
            var nlcolor = '#000070'         
            var clcolor = '#700000'
            var sradius = 50
            var strokeWidth = 1

            function drawCircle(sx, sy, sradius, sstrokeWidth, containerID) {
                this.stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ container: containerID, width: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1), height: 2*(sradius+strokeWidth+1) });
                this.circleLayer = new Kinetic.Layer();

                //circle
                this.scircle = new Kinetic.Circle({
                    x: sx,
                    y: sy,
                    radius: sradius,
                    fill:  {
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    },
                    stroke: slcolor,
                    strokeWidth: sstrokeWidth
                });

                this.mouseover_eventA = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    this.off("click.eventB");
                    this.parent.draw();
                };
                this.scircle.on("mouseover.eventA", mouseover_eventA);


                this.mouseout_eventA = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, sfcolor, 0.5, smcolor, 1, slcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(slcolor);
                    this.off("click.eventB");
                    this.parent.draw();
                }
                this.scircle.on("mouseout.eventA", mouseout_eventA);

                this.click_eventA = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, cfcolor, 0.5, cmcolor, 1, clcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(clcolor);
                    this.off("mouseout.eventA");
                    this.off("mouseover.eventA");
                    this.off("click.eventA");
                    this.on("click.eventB", click_eventB);
                    this.parent.draw();
                };

                this.click_eventB = function() {
                    this.setFill({
                        start: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: 0
                        },
                        end: {
                            x: 0,
                            y: 0,
                            radius: sradius
                        },
                        colorStops: [0, nfcolor, 0.5, nmcolor, 1, nlcolor]
                    });
                    this.setStroke(nlcolor);
                    this.on("mouseout.eventA", mouseout_eventA);
                    this.on("mouseover.eventA", mouseover_eventA);
                    this.on("click.eventA", click_eventA);    
                    this.off("click.eventB");
                    this.parent.draw();
                };

                this.scircle.on("click.eventA", click_eventA);

                this.circleLayer.add(this.scircle);
                this.stage.add(this.circleLayer);
            }
            window.onload = function() {
                for (i=1; i<=6; i++){                   
                    drawCircle(sradius, sradius, sradius, strokeWidth, i.toString());
                }
            };
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <table border="2">
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="1"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="2"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="3"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="4"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="5"></div> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td> <div id="6"></div> </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
```

Comment: like you might have seen i am not so good in javascript, this is axactly what i am looking for! Thank you very much! Greets Ben Green

Answer (score 0):

You could make a group and add circles to it by using a for-loop (if i understood your problem correctly)

Check this out: http://jsfiddle.net/9vsps/2/

Comment: every circle schould be indipendent. and evry circle schould be able to get a position independent to the others. Because of this i make more stages than one and so on. If it were so easy it would be fantastic, but it isn't

Comment: You should be able to make the group non-draggable and then make individual circle properties by setting them via group[0] group[1] and so on.